# Git reset - branch is behind master

Tags: git

I made several commits (let's say with IDs: 1, 2, 3, 4) and then realized that I made a mistake in commit 3 and want to go back to the version of code at commit 2.

I did:

```
git reset --hard 2
```

Now git says:

```
On branch master. 
Your branch is behind origin/master by 11 commits and can be fast forwarded.
```

I am wondering how I can "push" my code so that everyone has this version.

Comment: git says : on the remote branch, there are 11 commits on top of your current commit (with id `2`). Do you want to trash away those 11 commits ? or do you want to just remove commit `3` from the list ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depending on what you need :

one way to just remove commit 3 from the history is :

```
$ git rebase -i <id of commit 2>
# an editor will open a text editor, asking you to describe what you want to do
# delete the line containing <commit 3>, save and exit
```

`git` will output some messages indicating its progress, and you should end up with a new master branch containing all the commits except `<commit 3>`.

You will then need to add the `--force-with-lease` option to push this edited `master` branch :

```
git push --force-with-lease origin master
```

Comment: I think it's better to take the habit to use '--force-with-lease' instead of '--force' to prevent to destroy unintentionally of commits pushed by someone else...

Comment: will this cause problems for other people?

Comment: @BKSpurgeon: yes, this may cause problems for other people. The first one is : you may delete some other commits. The second one is : this will modify the history visible to other users, and require them to manually deal with it. Google for 'git push --force'

Answer (score 3):

`git push -f origin` to force push and alter history of your repo.
Might be better to just `git revert` the 2 commits to keep history.

Comment: I would definitely suggest going the `git revert` route. Force pushing is hardly ever a good idea, and will require further steps to be taken on everyone else's local machine.

Comment: If it is not a big deal for others contributors, I highly prefer to force push to keep a good history in the long term (because having a good history is of underrated!) instead of doing a revert which is a short view action... But you're right, it's better to do it if you're alone in your branch or if you could warn or decide with others.

Answer (score 1):

The message you got indicates that you have already pushed commits 3 and 4, so a hard reset is **not** what you want to do - that command changes history, and you should never try to change the history of a commit that has been pushed. Instead, do a `git pull` (so that you are up to date). Then `git revert 3` to undo the changes you made in commit 3.